# Insertar valor en celda especifica con Openpyxl - python

Tags: python, openpyxl

Tengo este código donde recientemente me ayudaron en este foro que sirve para hacer un csv que jala toda una tabla de una DataBase y además añade unos headers extra.

El código funciona bien pero quisiera hacer uso de **Openpyxl** para asignar valores a una celda especifica. He leido que con esa libreria puedo hacer eso pero no se como adaptarla al codigo de abajo.

Digamos que quiero agregar "Saludos" en la celda "H,3". ¿Cómo hacer eso?

```
def export():
    conn = sqlite3.connect("Example.db")
    cur=conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM Table1")
    rows=cur.fetchall()
    csv_path = "output.csv"
    with open(csv_path, "w", newline="") as csv_file:        
        csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)

        # Write headers.
        csv_writer.writerow([i[0] for i in cur.description]+ 
        ["Columna","columnaa2","columna3"])
        res = [i[0] for i in cur.description]+["Columna","columna2","columna3"]
        data = {k:[] for k in res}
        df = pd.DataFrame(data)

        # Write data.
        csv_writer.writerows(rows)
```

Comment: la celda `H3` corresponde a una columna en especifico??

Comment: Es una simple celda vacia, me gustaria agregar ahí contenido. Pero sigueindo el ejemplo del codigo seria en la columna "Columna"

Comment: puedes hacerlo tanto con openpyxl como con pandas, pero creo que no estas eligiendo el camino correcto para hacer tu programa. ¿De que trata tu programa?

Comment: La verdad soy nuevo en progrmacion, apenas ayer supe de pandas de ahi la idea de usar openpyxl.  Mi programa sirve para llevar un registro de usuarios. donde con un llamado jalo los datos de una persona y a esos datos asignarles nuevos campos, precisamente en celdas especificas

Comment: los datos de una persona los traes de una BD y luego lo exportas a un csv, correcto?

Comment: Si es correcto @Christian

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127930/discussion-between-christian-and-siro27).

Comment: podes evitarte algunas lineas si usas pandas.read_sql junto a la solucion de Christian.

Comment: @Carmoreno esa sería buena opción de esa forma evita hacer el zip. No he trabajado con esa función por  lo que me limite a dar una respuesta de lo que conozco, pero bien visto he!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nuevamente insisto en que pandas es mejor opción para esto, pues si la celda que señalas es el valor de una columna es mejor y más fácil *agregarlo* con pandas, esto gracias a sus <del>bonitos</del> hermosos *DataFrames* que nos permiten trabajar de forma ordenada con los datos.

Para esta ocasión lo único que necesitamos es obtener las columnas y la información de las personas, luego *combinaremos* esos datos usando la función `zip()` y finalmente lo convertiremos a un diccionario y listo!, pandas ya podrá armar nuestro *DataFrame*

Al utilizar pandas tampoco nos hace falta abrir un archivo (usando `open()`) esto nos permite ahorrarnos unas líneas de código. Para poder *escribir* o guardar el resultado la forma de hacer es *exportando* el *DataFrame* ya sea a un archivo `csv`, `Excel`, etc.

```py
def export():
    #convertimos a listas las tuplas que contiene la variable rows
    rows = [list(row) for row in rows]

    #para agregar un dato a una fila, accedemos a la fila
    rows[4].append("HOLA") #fila 5, agregamos el dato HOLA

    #obtenemos las columnas
    cols = [i[0] for i in cur.description]+["Columna","columna2","columna3"]

    data = [dict(zip(cols, pers)) for pers in rows]

    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df.to_csv(csv_path, index=None)
```

La variable `rows` contiene los datos traídos por la consulta y estos vienen en forma de una lista de tuplas `[(dato1,...), (dato2,..),..]` entonces recorremos esa lista con una comprensión de lista y transformamos cada tupla en una lista, esto para poder agregar elementos, con eso ya tenemos cada datos, por ejemplo `[dato1,...]`, y este dato, que es la información de cada persona. Esto lo unimos con nuestra lista de columnas mediante la función `zip()`, lo que hace esta función es que *empareja* al primer dato con el primer elemento de la lista y no tenemos que preocuparnos por que haya más columnas que datos, pues si solo hay 6 datos, solo lo emparejará con 6 elementos de la lista `cols`.

El resultado de este *emparejamiento* lo convertimos a un diccionario, donde los primeros elementos (columnas) serán las claves y los segundo (datos de la persona) serán los valores, por esa razón importa el orden en `zip(cols,pers)` (primer elemento son las columnas y el segundo la información de las personas). Finalmente exportamos el *DataFrame* en formato csv e indicamos que no tome en cuenta el index (primera columna) con el argumento `index=None`.

Comment: Apoyo la idea de pandas y sus sensuales Dataframes si Openpyxl no es un must. +1

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta @Christian , ya lo acomodé en mi código pero aun no entiendo como agregar los valores en las celdas. ¿Cómo es ?

Comment: @Siro27 con el código que he dado ya se están agregando los datos, es como *exportar* tu base de datos.

Comment: Es exactamente lo que buscaba, muchas gracias por todo crack